# React component Typescript for lodash helper

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, lodash

I have the following component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import throttle from 'lodash.throttle';

interface Props {
  withScroll: boolean;
}

class Image extends Component<Props, {}> {
  throttledWindowScroll?: typeof throttle;

  componentDidMount() {
    const { withScroll } = this.props;

    if (withScroll) {
      this.throttledWindowScroll = throttle(this.handleWindowScroll, 100);
      window.addEventListener('scroll', this.throttledWindowScroll);
    }
  }


  componentWillUnmount() {
    if (this.throttledWindowScroll) {
      this.throttledWindowScroll.cancel();
    }
  }

  handleWindowScroll = () => {
    // Do something
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div />
    );
  }
}

export default Image;
```

I also have `@types/lodash.throttle` installed which seems to be getting picked up fine.

My issue with this component is Typescript errors on the `this.throttledWindowScroll`.

```
Type '(() => void) & Cancelable' is not assignable to type '(<T extends (...args: any) => any>(func: T, wait?: number | undefined, options?: ThrottleSettings | undefined) => T & Cancelable) | undefined'.
  Type '(() => void) & Cancelable' is not assignable to type '<T extends (...args: any) => any>(func: T, wait?: number | undefined, options?: ThrottleSettings | undefined) => T & Cancelable'.
    Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'T & Cancelable'.
      Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'T'.
```

And on the second one:

```
Argument of type '(<T extends (...args: any) => any>(func: T, wait?: number | undefined, options?: ThrottleSettings | undefined) => T & Cancelable) | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'EventListenerOrEventListenerObject'.
  Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'EventListenerOrEventListenerObject'.
```

Plus an error on the usage of `.cancel()` method:

```
Property 'cancel' does not exist on type '<T extends (...args: any) => any>(func: T, wait?: number, options?: ThrottleSettings) => T & Cancelable'.
```

So the issue is with my 1 line of code: `throttledWindowScroll?: typeof throttle;`

If I changed that definition to `() => void`, I get an error about the cancel method not existing on it.

What's the correct way to handle imported libraries like this (noting it does have a type definition file).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This definition is incorrect

```
throttledWindowScroll?: typeof throttle
```

Using throttle returns `T & Cancelable`. `typeof throttle` on the other hand is a function. Change it to

```
throttledWindowScroll: ReturnType<typeof throttle>
```

Comment: Trying to reference handleWindowScroll there in a static property definition throws this error: `Cannot find name 'handleWindowScroll'.`

Comment: You can try `this.handleWindowScroll` or use the type directly.

Comment: First option throws this error: `Cannot find name 'this'.`
Second option throws this error: `Cannot find name 'Cancelable'.`.

Comment: Ok forget the first and Import the cancelable type from the type definition. Try full qualifying it as `lodash.Cancelable`

Comment: Aight I'm looking at the type definitions, and lodash doesn't actually export the Cancelable interface, which could be problem. This is the interface Cancelable which is needed to fully define that type. `interface Cancelable {  cancel(): void; flush(): void;  }`

Comment: Okay I have a fix.

Comment: Exellent that removes all errors! Thanks for finding this solution